Join data from table in Oracle database
I have two table as shown here:
Table tb_lose:
tb_lose
And table tb_profit:
tb_profit
I need to join the two tables and get a result like this:
result
All tables, code, I use SQL Server for example. I want implement this in an Oracle database.
Thanks!
I try to join the tables using this code:
with lose_tmp as
(
    select * from TB_Lose
),
profit_tmp as
(
    select * from TB_Profit
),
tmp_5 as 
(
    select a.Level, a.Lose, a.Name, b.Profit
    from lose_tmp a
    join 
        (select Level, Profit, Name from profit_tmp) b
             on a.Name = b.Name and a.Level = b.Level
    where a.Level = 5
),
tmp_10 as 
(
    select a.Level, a.Lose, a.Name, b.Profit
    from lose_tmp a
    join 
        (select Level, Profit, Name from profit_tmp) b
             on a.Name = b.Name and a.Level = b.Level
    where a.Level = 10
)
select 
    a.Name,
    v5.Lose Lose_5,
    v5.Profit Profit_5,
    v10.Lose Lose_10,
    v10.Profit Profit_10
from 
    lose_tmp a
left join 
    tmp_5 v5 on a.Name = v5.Name and a.Level = v5.Level
left join 
    tmp_10 v10 on a.Name = v10.Name and a.Level = v10.Level

And this is the result I get:
result

Welcome to Stack Overflow. Scripts to create the tables and set up sample data would help a lot, as people could try out your query themselves. Screenshots of data are hard to work with, especially since you haven't really described the exact issue you are having.

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

Please describe in words what the query is supposed to do. This: join (select Level, Profit, Name from profit_tmp) b should be shortened to join profit_tmp b by the way. It makes no sense to join a subquery, when the subquery selects all rows from the table. It just makes the query less readable.

Aggregate both tables using conditional aggregation (CASE expression inside the aggregation function). Then full outer join the results.
with
  lose_agg as
  (
    select
      l.name,
      sum(case when l.level = 5 then l.lose end) as lose_5,
      sum(case when l.level = 10 then l.lose end) as lose_10
    from tb_lose l
    group by l.name
  ),
  profit_agg as
  (
    select
      p.name,
      sum(case when p.level = 5 then p.profit end) as profit_5,
      sum(case when p.level = 10 then p.profit end) as profit_10
    from tb_profit p
    group by p.name
  )
select name, l.lose_5, p.profit_5, l.lose_10, p.profit_10 
from lose_agg l
full outer join profit_agg p using (name)
order by name;

In standard SQL we would rather use the FILTER clause for conditional aggregation, but neither of the two DBMS features this, yet:
sum(l.lose) filter (where l.level = 5) as lose_5,

SQL Server does not support the standard SQL USING clause. In SQL Sever the main query must be:
select
  coalesce(p.name, l.name) as name,
  l.lose_5,
  p.profit_5,
  l.lose_10,
  p.profit_10
from lose_agg l
full outer join profit_agg p on p.name = l.name
order by coalesce(p.name, l.name);

This works both in SQL Server and in Oracle.

In Oracle, you can PIVOT:
SELECT COALESCE(l.name, p.name) AS name,
       l.lose_5,
       p.profit_5,
       l.lose_10,
       p.profit_10
FROM   tb_lose
       PIVOT( SUM(lose) FOR lvl IN (5 AS Lose_5, 10 AS Lose_10) ) l
       FULL OUTER JOIN
       tb_profit
       PIVOT( SUM(profit) FOR lvl IN (5 AS Profit_5, 10 AS Profit_10) ) p
       ON l.name = p.name OR (l.name IS NULL AND p.name IS NULL)

Which, for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE tb_lose (name VARCHAR(3), lvl INT, lose INT);
INSERT INTO tb_lose (name, lvl, lose) VALUES ('GOL', 10, 12300);
INSERT INTO tb_lose (name, lvl, lose) VALUES ('USD',  5, 43560);
INSERT INTO tb_lose (name, lvl, lose) VALUES ('AUD', 10, 90430);
INSERT INTO tb_lose (name, lvl, lose) VALUES ('USD', 10, 1200);
INSERT INTO tb_lose (name, lvl, lose) VALUES (NULL,  NULL, NULL);

CREATE TABLE tb_profit (name VARCHAR(3), lvl INT, profit INT);
INSERT INTO tb_profit (name, lvl, profit) VALUES ('GOL', 10, 98000);
INSERT INTO tb_profit (name, lvl, profit) VALUES ('USD', 10, 65000);
INSERT INTO tb_profit (name, lvl, profit) VALUES ('USD',  5, 83700);
INSERT INTO tb_profit (name, lvl, profit) VALUES ('AUD', 10, 38210);
INSERT INTO tb_profit (name, lvl, profit) VALUES (NULL,  NULL, NULL);

Outputs:



NAME
LOSE_5
PROFIT_5
LOSE_10
PROFIT_10




GOL
null
null
12300
98000


USD
43560
83700
12000
65000


AUD
null
null
90430
38210


null
null
null
null
null



Oracle fiddle
In SQL Server, it is similar:
SELECT COALESCE(l.name, p.name) AS name,
       l.[5] AS lose_5,
       p.[5] AS profit_5,
       l.[10] AS lose_10,
       p.[10] AS profit_10
FROM   tb_lose
       PIVOT( SUM(lose) FOR lvl IN ([5], [10]) ) l
       FULL OUTER JOIN
       tb_profit
       PIVOT( SUM(profit) FOR lvl IN ([5], [10]) ) p
       ON l.name = p.name OR (l.name IS NULL AND p.name IS NULL)

SQL Server fiddle

Oracle:
One of the options to do it in Oracle is using MODEL clause where it is possible to address your dataset's rows and columns pretty much as addressing cells in Excel sheet.
Below is the code that works with your sample data and with some added rows (CHF, EUR) as a sample for possibility of non existing matching rows in both tables (having just lose or just profit row):
WITH  --  S a m p l e    D a t a :
    tb_lose ( NAME, LVL, LOSE ) AS 
        ( Select 'GOL', 10, 12300  From Dual Union All
          Select 'USD',  5, 43560  From Dual Union All
          Select 'AUD', 10, 90430  From Dual Union All
          Select 'USD', 10, 1200   From Dual Union All
          Select 'CHF', 5, 2000    From Dual          -- added row
        ), 
    tb_profit ( NAME, LVL, PROFIT ) AS
        ( Select 'GOL', 10, 98000  From Dual Union All
          Select 'USD', 10, 65000  From Dual Union All
          Select 'USD',  5, 83700  From Dual Union All
          Select 'AUD', 10, 38210  From Dual Union All
          Select 'EUR', 10,  3000  From Dual          -- added row
        )

... the innermost query unions the data which are then summed and modeled for final aggregation removing duplicate rows per currencies ...
--      S Q L :
SELECT    NAME, 
          Max(LOSE_5) as LOSE_5, Max(PROFIT_5) as PROFIT_5, 
          Max(LOSE_10) as LOSE_10, Max(PROFIT_10) as PROFIT_10
FROM    ( Select  * 
          From    ( Select    NAME, LVL, Sum(LOSE) as LOSE, Sum(PROFIT) as PROFIT,
                              0 as LOSE_5, 0 as PROFIT_5, 0 as LOSE_10, 0 as PROFIT_10
                    From    ( Select NAME, LVL, LOSE, 0 as PROFIT From tb_lose   
                             Union All   
                              Select NAME, LVL, 0, PROFIT From tb_profit 
                            ) c
                    Group By  c.NAME, c.LVL
                    Order By  c.NAME, c.LVL
                  ) 
                  MODEL   Dimension By ( NAME, LVL )
                          Measures ( LOSE, PROFIT, LOSE_5, PROFIT_5, LOSE_10, PROFIT_10 )
                  RULES   ( LOSE_5[ANY, 5] = LOSE[CV(), CV()],   -- CV() is Current Value of the respective dimension
                            PROFIT_5[ANY, 5] = PROFIT[CV(), CV()], 
                            LOSE_10[ANY, 10] = LOSE[CV(), CV()], 
                            PROFIT_10[ANY, 10] = PROFIT[CV(), CV()]
                          )
        )
GROUP BY NAME
ORDER BY NAME

/*
NAME     LOSE_5   PROFIT_5    LOSE_10  PROFIT_10
---- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
AUD           0          0      90430      38210
CHF        2000          0          0          0    -- added
EUR           0          0          0       3000    -- added
GOL           0          0      12300      98000
USD       43560      83700       1200      65000   */

